# nextjs 13 TypeError: children is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

This is Home page:

```
export default async function Home() {
  # console.log(data) it is populated
  const { data } = getAllArts();
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
        <ArtList arts={data}>
          {(art: Art) => <ArtCard key={art.id} art={art} disabled={false} />}
        </ArtList>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I use [render-props](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) technique in `ArtList` component:

```
interface ArtListProps {
  arts: Art[];
  // using React.ReactNode causes type is not callable error
  children: FunctionComponent;
}

export default function ArtList({ arts, children }: ArtListProps) {
  return (
    <section className="grid md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-4 mb-5">
      {arts.map((art) => children(art))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

but I get error:

```
- error src/components/ui/art/ArtList.tsx (15:25) @ children
- error TypeError: children is not a function
    at eval (./src/components/ui/art/ArtList.tsx:12:35)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ArtList (./src/components/ui/art/ArtList.tsx:12:24)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Same code was working with this package versions:

```
"next": "11.1.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
```

current package versions:

```
next": "13.4.19",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `ArtListProps`?

Comment: @Mentlegen I updated the post. But I dont think that it is a typescript type error

Comment: This will be much easier for you if you use a normal prop instead `<ArtList arts={arts} item={art => <ArtCard art={art} />} />`. Overriding `children` is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to the last part of the documentation you provided, is probably to extract the rendering part as a standalone method rather than an inline anonymous function for the sake of readability. Once you do that, it will all become so much more clear how this concept works.

Start with your `<Home />` component, we can refactor the body of

```
<ArtList arts={data}>
  {(art: Art) => <ArtCard key={art.id} art={art} disabled={false} />}
</ArtList>
```

(Let's disregard the syntax error for now) to a method --

```
  const renderList = (arts: Art[]) => (
    <div>
      {arts.map((art, i) => {
        return <ArtCard key={i} art={art} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
```

and pass it to the `<ArtList>` component as props like how official documentation at the final portion does with prop name of `render`  --

```
<ArtList arts={data} render={renderList} />
```

You probably are able to follow where I am going with it now, and the rest of the work are pretty much the same as what you already have and what official doc is going --

```
export const ArtList: React.FC<{
  arts: Art[]
  render: (arts: Art[]) => JSX.Element
}> = ({ arts, render }) => {
  return (
    <section className="grid md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-4 mb-5">
      {render(arts)}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Hopefully this helps. Here's the link to CodeSandbox how it look like in action -- https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sound-65kx3z

Cheers